# Need help in solving an exponential equation

Tags: exponentiation

Find integer $x$ so that $$5\cdot5^{2x}-24\cdot2^x - 5 = 0$$

I know there is an approach as we can show the function $f(x):= 5\cdot5^{2x}-24\cdot2^x - 5$ is injective.

So, the equation can have at most one solution. And, basically, if we can guess the solution, that's it.

Is there any other way to resolve this equation?
Here is what I've tried:

$$5\cdot(5^{2x} - 1)=24\cdot2^x$$

The last digit of the left member can be $0$, and the last digit of the right member can be $2$, $4$, $6$ or $8$. Therefore, there is no solution in $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: There is no solution in the integers.

Comment: What makes you think that there is a closed-form solution?

Comment: I said there is at most one solution, that implies also no solution. But i wanted to see other interpretations

Comment: Your fifth paragraph suggests that you are only interested in integer solutions. You should state this up front.

Comment: The function is not injective. It has a value arbitrarily close to $-5$ for numbers that are negative enough, then it has a value of $-24$ at $x=0$, and a *positive* value at $x=10$. This means that (at least) the function hits all the values between $-5$ and $-24$ at least twice.

Comment: There's a solution at ~ 0.669779696767582773421707492251639911727427155347469297463756557032620457554426183508559809630030995857262338193300760

Comment: [Here's a graph](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwryMkv0TBV0FIwjdMw0qrQVNBVMDIBco3iKoBMUx0uBQ1dUx0FAz0LTR2F9KLMlJzMvNRiW6XcxKz8IiVNANxoD-E=&lang=sage)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This equation has not solution for $x\ge 0$, since $5\not| 24\cdot 2^x$. For $x<0$, we define $y=-x$ and write the equation as
$$
{5(25^{-y}-1)=24\cdot 2^{-y}\implies 
\\
5\cdot 2^y\cdot (1-25^y)=24\cdot 25^y\implies 
\\
2^y\cdot (1-25^y)=24\cdot 5^{2y-1},
}
$$which, again, has no solution for $y\ge 1$ since $5\not | 2^y\cdot(1-25^y)$ and **the equation has no integer solution**.